# The calculation result in MS Access will be changed once applied on filter

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have this question about the calculation field in Access, the results gonna be change once applied on the filters in the report or pivot table. And I'm not sure that should I use Domain function instead?

The calculation field in the query is a percentage. Something like the following one:

```
Yes+YC Sore: Count(IIf([tblAnswers2015]![HQ Answer(s)]="y" Or [tblAnswers2015]![HQ Answer(s)]="yc",1))/Count(*)
```

I wish to have a average over the group. but I'm kind of worried that the data gonna be changed, if I filter the report or pivot table by other category.The average field in the report and pivot table is something like the following formula.

```
=Avg([Yes+YC Sore])
```

But if I use functions instead. Should I put the filter content into the criteria filed?

Answer (score 0):

Try with Sum:

```
Yes+YC Sore: Sum(IIf([tblAnswers2015]![HQ Answer(s)]="y" Or [tblAnswers2015]![HQ Answer(s)]="yc", 1, 0)) / Count(*)
```

or:

```
Yes+YC Sore: Sum(Abs([tblAnswers2015]![HQ Answer(s)]="y" Or [tblAnswers2015]![HQ Answer(s)]="yc")) / Count(*)
```

Comment: Dear Gustav, I tried both of them but the value still changing in the report once i applied on the filter. Thank u so much for the help. But do u know if it is possible, to keep the group average result s the same when i filter out something, like some other empty columns?

Comment: I see. No, then may have to pull the calculation from DSum/DCount. If that is too slow, you may use a subquery instead.

Comment: Got it Thanks but I tried with Dfunction in the report, it only applied on the whole sheet, but i still need some thing could have a fixed group average. thanks any way